# How to detect if a resource exists using list option and JMESPath (az-cli)?

Tags: powershell, azure-cli, jmespath

I am trying to detech if a given query returns any results and branch based on that. I'm using PowerShell and this works

`(az network vnet list --query "[?name=='testvnet']" | ConvertFrom-Json).Length`

but then I was wondering if this would be possible with JMESPath and tried variations of

`az network vnet list --query "length([?name=='testvnet'])"`

but it appears this is not possible using JMESPath. Or is there a way?

According to the documentation at https://jmespath.readthedocs.io/en/stable/specification.html#length there is a function called `length` and I understand it work like that.

The error for this particular example is

```
az : az network vnet list: error: argument --query: invalid jmespath_type value: "length([?name=='testvnet']"
At line:1 char:1
+ az network vnet list --query "length([?name=='testvnet'])"
```

The missing end parenthesis in the error message is suspicious. This may be due to using `az cli` in a PowerShell console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there. Try

```
az network vnet list --query "[?name == 'testvnet'] | length(@)"
```

Comment: Yes! Tried and it works! It helps to ask, it seems, as I missed this `@` while trying with `*`. Life is better now, this must be something many others need to do too.